# Centering elements in navigation header html css

Tags: html, css, element, center, centering

I have made a navigation header (i.d.k. how you call it) and I want some text to be in the middle of it.

It basically is a black bar, with some navigation buttons on the right (e.g. Home, about us, info, gallery...) a logo on the left, and now I want some text in the middle of that bar. I can't get it to work.

This is the code I have so far.

```css
/* Global settings */

* {
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Header settings */

.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #212121;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

.header ul {
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
}

.header li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header li:hover {
  background-color: #616161;
}

.header a {
  display: block;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.header img {
  height: 100%;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  float: left;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #FAFAFA;
  Line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>The text I want to be centered</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
     <img src="" alt="Logo" />
     <h1>The text I want to be centered</h1>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Info</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     </ul>       
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Header settings */
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #212121;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  padding:0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header ul {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header li:hover {
  background-color: #616161;
}

.header a {
  display: block;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.header img {
  height: 100%;
  color: #FAFAFA;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #FAFAFA;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

What the above will do is put the text at equal distances from the logo and menu. So, the text won't be precisely centered, but will probably look more "correct".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [Flexible Box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). Flexbox does have compatibility issues in older versions of IE, but for non-dinosaur browsers it works really well. Here is a [good link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for learning more about it.

You may have to adjust the size of the `h1` to avoid text wrapping, as well as fix some of the borders on the `li`.

***Edit:* I added `flex: 1 1 0` to `.flex-item` which will make all of the elements the same size thereby centering the text. I removed the `flex` rules from the individual elements as well. This will look best on wide screens!**

```css
* {
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

div.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #212121;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: auto;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}


/* Used to make 3 sections in the head*/

h1.flex-item {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: #FAFAFA;
}

ul.flex-item {
  display: flex;
}

img.flex-item {
  color: #FAFAFA;
}


/* Used to make NAV*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li.flex-item-li {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}

li.flex-item-li a {
  display: block;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

li.flex-item-li:hover {
  background-color: #616161;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <img class="flex-item" src="" alt="Logo" />
    <h1 class="flex-item">Text I want to be centered</h1>
    <ul class="flex-item">
      <li class="flex-item-li"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li class="flex-item-li"><a href="">Info</a></li>
      <li class="flex-item-li"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="flex-item-li"><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I played around a bit and looked into some tutorials about flexboxes, but it still doesn't seem to be working. It might be I didn't explain my question clear enough. I want the text to centered in the whole black box. not equally distanced from the menu and the logo. Your solution would work if I can exclude the menu and the logo from the flexbox.

Comment: @WernerSchoemaker Oh. Essentially you want the text to be behind the Nav elements? Gimmie a sec...

Comment: Just to clarify things, I created a little sketch of what I am looking for. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzqvOBblncladkV6a1dxNkszWlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @WernerSchoemaker I made an edit that I think does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is already in the center, but it is being pushed away from its original central position because of the menu on the right and logo on the left.

So to solve this issue just pull the text towards the center by adding margins.
Like this:

```
.header h1 {
    color: #FAFAFA;
    Line-height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -200px;
}
```

View this code snippet in full page for the result:

```css
* {
  font-family: Roboto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Header settings */

.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #212121;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

.header ul {
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
}

.header li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header li:hover {
  background-color: #616161;
}

.header a {
  display: block;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.header img {
  height: 100%;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  float: left;
}

.header h1 {
  color: #FAFAFA;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>The text I want to be centered</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="" alt="Logo" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I almost got it to work by placing only the navigation and the logo in a flex div. now I only need to get the flexdiv on top of the text. If someone could explain that real quick would be nice, but the biggest part is done.

http://codepen.io/werner1107/pen/EWMPVM

html:

```
    <body>
      <div class="header">
        <h1>The text I want to be centered</h1>
        <div class="test">
          <img src="" alt="Logo" />
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
    /* Global settings */
    * {
      font-family: Roboto;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    /*   border: 1px solid orange; */
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* Header settings */
    .header {
      height: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #212121;
    }

    .header h1 {
      color: #FAFAFA;
      line-height: 50px;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .test {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .test img {
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      color: #FAFAFA;
    }

    .test ul {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .test li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style-type: none;
      height: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .test a {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      color: #FAFAFA;
      width: 75px;
      line-height: 50px;
    }

    .test li:hover {
      background-color: #616161;
    }
```